# Problem with mapping function to column values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have a function like this:

```
def cal_info(data):
    if 0 <= data <= 600:
        return '1'
    elif 1000 <= data <= 2200:
        return '3'
    elif 2200 <= data <= 3500:
        return '7'
    elif 3500 <= data <= 7000:
        return '20'
    else:
        return 'None'
```

And I column in df with values from 0 to 7000.

And then I need to map this function to that column to get another column:

```
df = final_df.assign(new_col=map(cal_info, df['column1']))
```

But I'm getting this:

```
<map object at 0x7f8db8d63160>
```

Comment: Better here is binning, but if want use your solution `df = final_df.assign(new_col= df['column1'].map(cal_info))` or ``df = final_df.assign(new_col= df['column1'].apply(cal_info))``

Comment: @jezrael the first way is ok in both python 2 and python 3?

Comment: I hope yes, but more common are used `apply`